# Setting Socket Timeout value for HttpClient (4.3.3) doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: java, sockets, ubuntu, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some code that makes a POST request to a url basically. I set some default settings on the HttpClient instance in a Util class I use to create and maintain the HttpClient instance:

```
    cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    cm.setMaxTotal(100);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(500)
            .setConnectTimeout(10)
            .setSocketTimeout(2000)
            .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
            .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true).build();

    httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();
```

This code works perfectly when running locally on my mac running within IntelliJ. I test it by setting the socketTimeout to something like 5 ms. Throws a socket exception as expected. BTW, this is a standalone Java app. Doesn't run in a container.

My problem is when I push this app to an EC2 instance running ubuntu. When I perform the exact same test with the same version of the app by lowering the socket timeout to a really low value, it doesn't have any affect at all.

Any ideas why this is happening? Am I using this as it should be used? I basically want to make sure calls to this URL will not take any longer than 2 seconds total. Is this the proper way to do that, or do I need to spawn a thread for every request (seems like overkill) to monitor each request and kill it after the timeout period?

Comment: I wouldn't say a connect timeout of 20ms or a read timeout of 5ms or 2s were exactly 'using it as it should be used', but it should work.

Comment: What I need is a way to monitor the full request. I've realized the socketTimeout will ONLY throw an exception if a socket is blocked waiting for data BETWEEN data packets. What I want is a way to kill off a full request if it takes say over 2 seconds. This is easy with an Async method. But with synchronous HttpClient, how can I do it?